# Problems removing desktop shortcuts from multiple user's desktops

Tags: windows, shortcuts, desktop

Similar issue as here but didn't solve my problem (I don't have any Public Desktop folder): [Problems removing desktop shortcuts from multiple user's desktops - Microsoft Community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/problems-removing-desktop-shortcuts-from-multiple/2857c8a9-e2b4-485f-a219-41e49d0fd79c)

After installing a game, on user's A desktop I have a shortcut to that game. I then changed this shortcut, adding some command-line parameters.

On user's B desktop, I saw another shortcut to the same game, which was not needed, so I moved it to another folder. I later found out the shortcut on user A's desktop disappeared. Going back to user B's desktop to investigate, I saw that the shortcut in B's desktop also has all the changes I made to the shortcut in A's desktop, which is strange. I had thought they were 2 separate `lnk` files in 2 different folders.

For a quick fix I can just move the shortcut from B's desktop to A's desktop, but why did this happen? How can I prevent it from happening again with other shortcuts?

Comment: `I don't have any Public Desktop folder` - did you break your windows?

Comment: Ok I see it now. It was probably hidden, that's why I didn't see it. I can access and see 2, 3 shortcuts, it but that's not where my game shortcut were located, which are in `C:\Users\UserA\Desktop` and `C:\Users\UserB\Desktop` before I moved one of them.

Answer (score 0):

The shortcut was probably installed in the
[CommonDesktopDirectory](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder#System_Environment_SpecialFolder_CommonDesktopDirectory) special folder, which usually is
`C:\Users\Public\Desktop`.

The `CommonDesktopDirectory` is defined as :

> The file system directory that contains files and folders that appear on the desktop for all users.

I think that by manipulating the shortcut on one user's desktop has
affected another user, because this shortcut is common to both users.

Reference :
[How to make a desktop shortcut available for all users in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/984866/how-to-make-a-desktop-shortcut-available-for-all-users-in-windows-10).

Comment: My game shortcut were not in Public Desktop, but in `C:\Users\UserA\Desktop` and `C:\Users\UserB\Desktop` before I moved one of them.

Comment: If the two shortcuts on the two user desktops were to the same target, changing the target would affect both. But otherwise, they should both be completely independent one from the other, unless in the public desktop.